# some preg_replace need fix

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi I have some problems with preg replace. I'm fixing some php script with separating the html tags from php so I tried this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/print(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ((.*?)));/', '?>print(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ($1));<?php');
```

but it doesn't work in the `agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ` there are variables here some samples:

```
print(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ($pnjkaa235));
print(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ($srpmjk236));
print(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ($ydxxqb237));
```

Comment: You need to escape your `(` with `\(` for the literal representation of the value rather then the regular expression symbol.

Comment: wow, how did this get 4 downvotes? escape sequences are something not **that** easy to find on your own, if you don't know that that's a thing. plus, the question provides the own attempt and examples.

Comment: i don't know but thanks to Jon and s.webbandit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first part of `preg_replace` with `/print\(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ\((.*?)\)\);/`

You also need to add a thrid parameter to `preg_replace` that holds the text you are searching through: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: tanks mate you help me fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

`'/print(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ((.*?)));/'` => `'/print\(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ\((.*?)\)\);/'`